# EF 6.1 not reading Table attribute and not generating TPT

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Having a bit of a problem with EF not generating the correct database structure.

I have the following code:

```
    [Table("Email")]
    public class Email
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmailID { get; set; }
        public EmailAddress From { get; set; }
        public String Subject { get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
        public EmailAddress To { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<EmailAddress> BCC { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<EmailAddress> CC { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    }

   [Table("BookingRequests")]
   public class BookingRequest : Email
   {
       public String Testing123 { get; set; }
   }
```

This didn't work, it was still putting Testing123 into the Email table. I thought perhaps it's because I only have one subclass of Email, so I added this:

```
[Table("TestingTable")]
public class OtherTest : Email
{
    public string OtherVal { get; set; }
}
```

But I still get the same problem as before (OtherVal and Testing123) and stuck in the Email table. All the examples for TPT that I've found only mention adding the Table() attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and added it to my project - which is using EF6.1

This is the migration it created:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Email",
            c => new
                {
                    EmailID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Subject = c.String(),
                    Text = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EmailID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingRequests",
            c => new
                {
                    EmailID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Testing123 = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EmailID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Email", t => t.EmailID)
            .Index(t => t.EmailID);

    }
```

So it should work...have you got any code that uses FluentAPI?

Answer (score 0):

EF uses what is called [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (or Table per Hierarchy) while you are expecting inheritance to be mirrored in the DB in a different way. [This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bursteg/2007/09/30/how-to-model-inheritance-in-databases/) describes the three ways generally used. EF has to implement one, and it's not picked the one you expect.